# Change bootstrap cols on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello everyone I have page with 2 cols and in each col i have boxes.

```
[6][6]
 a  b
 a  b
 a  b
```

How can I change order to have:

```
a
b
a
b
a
b
```

Is it possible?
I want it only on mobile.Here is my page structure:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>b</div>
    <div>b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with your current HTML structure. However if you can change a structure then you would be able to use grid classes to target xs devices:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div>b</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div>b</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div>b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/j2oHBuJUi1FWmiugy0nr?p=info

Comment: I thought about it before post question here but I want to see if there is another option. Your answer is what I want to do. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just split your content to separate col-md-6 each like

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>b</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>b</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

does your layout allow this? e.g. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doPogJ